# How to get Greek symbols (alpha, beta) in Cinema4D text

Tags: cinema4d

I'm trying to get Greek symbols in a Cinema4D text object that is extruded, however when I select the Symbol font the text disappears from the viewport. I can still see it in the text input frame, but it's not visible in the render.

How can I get an extruded Greek letter in Cinema4D?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't be 100% certain, but the problem is most likely your font type.  I'm not familiar with Cinema4D specifically, but some fonts are raster based for given point sizes and some are vector based.  Most extrusions require you to have a vector based format and if the font is raster, then you aren't going to get any result.

The best bet is either to find a vector based greek font or to use something like illustrator to create a vector path that fits the characters and import that vector document for extrusion.